# How to embed Matplotlib plot in PyQT widget?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to embed Matplotlib plot in my PyQt app using QWidget. This is the code of the widget script.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from entropia import entropy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

class MplWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        self.vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setLayout(self.vertical_layout)

    def draw(self):

        QWidget.update(self)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

        fs = 500
        f = random.randint(1, 100)
        ts = 1/fs
        length_of_signal = 100
        t = np.linspace(0,1,length_of_signal)

        cosinus_signal = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
        sinus_signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

        self.canvas.axes.clear()
        self.canvas.axes.plot(t, cosinus_signal)
        self.canvas.axes.plot(t, sinus_signal)
        self.canvas.axes.legend(('cosinus', 'sinus'),loc='upper right')
        self.canvas.axes.set_title('Cosinus - Sinus Signal')
        self.canvas.draw()
```

I want the plot to be displayed after the pushbutton in another script is clicked. Unfortunately, this is not working. Button is connected to the function, though. If I do something like print(fs) in the "draw" method I see the variable in the python terminal when the button gets clicked.

This is how it looks when the button gets clicked:

[image]

When I move the whole thing to the **init** method the plot is displayed.

```
class MplWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        self.vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(self.vertical_layout)

        fs = 500
        f = random.randint(1, 100)
        ts = 1/fs
        length_of_signal = 100
        t = np.linspace(0,1,length_of_signal)

        cosinus_signal = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
        sinus_signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

        self.canvas.axes.clear()
        self.canvas.axes.plot(t, cosinus_signal)
        self.canvas.axes.plot(t, sinus_signal)
        self.canvas.axes.legend(('cosinus', 'sinus'),loc='upper right')
        self.canvas.axes.set_title('Cosinus - Sinus Signal')
        self.canvas.draw()
```

[image]

So, what can I do to display the plot only after calling it from another method?

Comment: Shouldn't the call to `QWidget.update(self)` come after the figure canvas gets updated?

Comment: You never called `self.draw()` in the constructor. `QWidget.update(self)` shouldn't be required

Comment: When I call self.draw() in the constructor it plots at the start of the app and I don't want that.

Comment: Well you could call `self.draw()` from anywhere. I connected a `QPushButton.clicked` signal to self.draw and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I get it that I can call it from anywhere, but still it wasn't working for me. I've rewritten substantial part of the code and I've dropped the widget altogether, though.